# What is the issue seen below when clustering ejabberd 16.06 with 15.11?

Tags: ejabberd

I see an issue when trying to cluster ejabberd 16.06 with already running 15.11. I issue join_cluster command from the 16.06 machine. On issuing list_cluster I see that that it has clustered with 15.11 version.
During the restart of 15.11 machine, I see that that ejabberd does not start at all, the logs indicate the below error:-

> *2016-08-17 11:36:54.479 [debug] <0.363.0> Supervisor ejabberd_sup started ejabberd_hooks:start_link() at pid <0.364.0>
>
>   2016-08-17 11:36:54.481 [debug] <0.32.0> Supervisor kernel_safe_sup started
>   pg2:start_link() at pid <0.366.0>
>
>   2016-08-17 11:36:54.499 [debug] <0.363.0> Supervisor ejabberd_sup started
>   ejabberd_node_groups:start_link() at pid <0.365.0>
>
>   2016-08-17 11:36:54.499 [debug] <0.363.0> Supervisor ejabberd_sup started
>   ejabberd_system_monitor:start_link() at pid <0.367.0>
>
>   2016-08-17 11:36:54.499 [error] <0.368.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.368.0> with 0
>   neighbours exited with reason: no case clause matching
>   [domain,server_host,pid,local_hint] in ejabberd_router:update_tables/0
>   line 397 in gen_server:init_it/6 line 330
>
>   2016-08-17 11:36:54.499 [error] <0.363.0> Supervisor ejabberd_sup had child ejabberd_router
>   started with ejabberd_router:start_link() at undefined exit with
>   reason no case clause matching [domain,server_host,pid,local_hint] in
>   ejabberd_router:update_tables/0 line 397 in context start_error
>
>   2016-08-17 11:36:54.502 [error] <0.37.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.37.0>
>   with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no such process or port in call
>   to gen_server:call(ejabberd_sup,
>   {start_child,{ejabberd_sm,{ejabberd_sm,start_link,[]},transient,1000,worker,[ejabberd_sm]}}, infinity) in application_master:init/4 line 133
>
>   2016-08-17 11:36:54.502 [info] <0.7.0> Application ejabberd exited with reason:
>   no such process or port in call to gen_server:call(ejabberd_sup,
>   {start_child,{ejabberd_sm,{ejabberd_sm,start_link,[]},transient,1000,worker,[ejabberd_sm]}}, infinity)*

**Is this something that is already known? Please can anyone help with this.**

**Also, Pub-sub functionality is broken in this cluster setup.**
I see the below error when trying to create profile using 15.11 ejabberd (that is already clustered with 16.06):-

> *2016-08-16 12:53:20.653 [debug] <0.400.0>@ejabberd_router:do_route:324 route from
>   {jid,<<>>,<<"pubsub.ejabberd">>,<<>>,<<>>,<<"pubsub.ejabberd">>,<<>>}
>   to
>   {jid,<<"xx-user">>,<<"xx.ejabberd">>,<<>>,<<"xx-user">>,<<"xx.ejabberd">>,<<>>}
>   packet
>   {xmlel,<<"iq">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"xx-user-57ae15fde4b057aa64db2a5c-19-1471331160286">>},{<<"type">>,<<"result">>}],[{xmlel,<<"pubsub">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">>}],[{xmlel,<<"create">>,[{<<"node">>,<<"AMS-profile1">>}],[]}]}]}
>
>   2016-08-16 12:53:20.653 [error] <0.400.0>@ejabberd_router:route:77
>   {{badrecord,route},[{ejabberd_router,do_route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_router.erl"},{line,364}]},{ejabberd_router,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_router.erl"},{line,75}]},{mod_pubsub,handle_info,2,[{file,"src/mod_pubsub.erl"},{line,859}]},{gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,593}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,659}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}
>   when processing:
>   {{jid,<<>>,<<"pubsub.ejabberd">>,<<>>,<<>>,<<"pubsub.ejabberd">>,<<>>},{jid,<<"xx-user">>,<<"xx.ejabberd">>,<<>>,<<"xx-user">>,<<"xx.ejabberd">>,<<>>},{xmlel,<<"iq">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"xx-user-57ae15fde4b057aa64db2a5c-19-1471331160286">>},{<<"type">>,<<"result">>}],[{xmlel,<<"pubsub">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">>}],[{xmlel,<<"create">>,[{<<"node">>,<<"AMS-profile1">>}],[]}]}]}}*

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same version of ejabberd on all your cluster nodes. There is not guarantee that a cluster will different version can work. It can work sometimes, but the general rule is that it is not expected to work.